# Question regarding name of style of photo

Tags: lens, digital, style

So, I am currently building a website and it's partially photogenic, therefore, I need really clean photos. I was looking for a style that would fit what kind of photos express who I am and what I am looking for and in doing so found another website that represents this. The link to the other person's personal website is below:

http://kirahug.com/

I was wondering what kind of shots her website is littered with? Basically the whole half body or full body, colorful background with depth, etc,. Do these have a name in the photography field?

Also, this might be an impossible question, but what kind of lens would be used for shots like this?

Thanks in advance for the response!

Comment: "mimicry of overposed, overprocessed, oversaturated stock photography"?

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stock photography. Not a style in a classical style in the meaning of that, but that's the type of the photographs on that website. As for "half body" - it's called [medium shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_(filmmaking)#By_field_size), very common in stock photography due to being a great way to show over-the-top body expression that's all too common in modern-day stock photography.

Comment: Ah yes! This was a term I saw that was most connected to the style of shots after doing some more searching. Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) Happy to help :) Remember to click the green tickbox next to the answer once you'll register! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that particular style has a name yet. The closest I know is "Pop Art" or "Pop Art Comic" style. 
An example of that style that comes to my mind is what Congstar (German telco reseller) uses in their adverts. The difference is that in your example the colour stile is already set up and then just taken a photo of it while for congstar a good deal of post editing is involved (I guess).

Comment: This does seem to be 'pop' oriented. I will make sure to look into this style. It certainly fits what I am trying to get out of a potential portfolio.